# Link with icon in Laravel 4

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-4, hyperlink, font-awesome

Can someone help to rewrite this, from HTML to Laravel4?

```
    <a href="index.php" ><span><i class="icon-home"></i></span> Home </a>
```

The route name for that page is just '/'.
I know how to write simple link in Laravel:

```
{{ HTML::link('/','Home) }}
```

But how can I add the span class with the font-awesome icon?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd just put the link in the href.

```
<a href="{{ url('/') }}"><span><i class="icon-home"></i></span> Home</a>
```

No need to generate all the rest through Laravel.

Answer (score 3):

What @Dries suggests is simple and very straightforward, but you really want to have it done entirely via Laravel, I would suggest writing a HTML macro, especially if you want more complex html structures to be involved. For example, here is a macro for `<a><img /></a>` structure:

```
    HTML::macro('image_link', function($url = '', $img='img/', $alt='', $param = false, $active=true, $ssl=false)
{
    $url = $ssl==true ? URL::to_secure($url) : URL::to($url);  
    $img = HTML::image($img,$alt);
    $link = $active==true ? HTML::link($url, '#', $param) : $img;
    $link = str_replace('#',$img,$link);
    return $link;
});
```

You could read more about it here: http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?pid=10467

Comment: It seems quite difficult.. anyway thanks for replying

Answer (score 0):

```
{!! HTML::decode(link_to(URL::previous(),
    '<i class="fa fa-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></i> Back',
    ['class' => 'btn btn-primary'])) !!}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!