# Laravel navigation bar not working after using a route with $id parameter?

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, laravel

I'm viewing table of users from MySQL database using laravel,andhow there is edit column and I need to use the $id parameter to redirect the user to another page and view the user details.
this is my route and it's working fine.

```
<td>
    <a href="{{ URL::to('userdetails',$user->id) }}"</a>
    Edit
</td>
```

but after going to this page that view user detials. my navigation bar url's start behaving weird.

when I view the users list my URL is

```
/osama/warehouse/public/index.php/userslist
```

when I view a specific users with an id the url is

```
/osama/warehouse/public/index.php/userdetails/1
```

until all good, but after that when I click on my home button on my navigation bar or other links I get an error because the URL not correct

```
/osama/warehouse/public/index.php/userdetails/home !!!
```

the right URL should be

```
/osama/warehouse/public/index.php/home
```

note I'm not using blade route or html url for my navigation bar,just pure HTML.the reason is I got css classes that I can't include in the html link.

Comment: Please provide your code for your "Home" button. And could you please elaborate why you are not using Laravel helper classes?

Comment: this is one of my navigation bar code and it's hard to write using blade.`<a <?php if ($_SESSION['navbar']=="dashboard"){echo 'class="active"';}?> href="home"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i> Dashboard</a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`URL::to()` doesn't prefix the URL with `/` so when you call it, you'll get "userslist" or "userdetails/1" back.

If you simply put a `/` into your call to `URL::to()`, it'll work fine:

```
<a href="{{ URL::to('/userdetails',$user->id) }}"></a>
```

You'll need to do this with all occurrences of `URL::to()` (eg. on your Home link).

In other news, there are a couple of other issues:

- your `<a>` tag is missing the close `>` - you just have `id) }}"</a>`
- your link is empty, because "Edit" is outside the tag. You probably want `id) }}">Edit</a>`

Comment: when I write the url this way `<a href="/{{ URL::to('/userdetails',$user->id) }}"></a>` the URL become like this `http://localhost/http://localhost/osama/warehouse/public/index.php/userdetails/6` two localhosts ?

Comment: Sorry, I had an extra `/` in there - you don't want one at the start of the `href`. See the updated answer, it should be correct now. My bad

Comment: thanks joe, the solution like you said before ,I have to change the navigation bar URLS ...After long search I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19427657/link-with-icon-in-laravel-4 it help me ,anyhow I appreciate your help

Comment: Any chance of an upvote if it was helpful, and/or a correct-answer if it's correct? :-)

Comment: for that `/` it's helpful ,but for the navigation bar it's not helpful .

Comment: Your question says that your URLs are wrong, the answer fixes your URLs. I'm not quite sure I follow you

Answer (score 0):

You should really use the helper classes that Laravel provides.
This kind of problem would be avoided.

Examples using Laravel:

```
<a href="{{ URL::to('home') }}">Dashboard</a>
<a href="{{ url('home') }}">Dashboard</a>
```

If you insist in not using them, you probably have to modify your links to be relative to your root by adding a slash at the beggining:

```
<a href="/home">Dashboard</a>
```

You should change all URL's that needs to be relative to your root.

Comment: thanks for your help I just found the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19427657/link-with-icon-in-laravel-4 the code that useful for me is `<a href="{{ url('home') }}" ><span><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i></span> Dashboard </a>`

Answer (score 0):

thanks guys guys the solution is to change the navigation bar link's  `{{ url('home') }}` this link work everywhere using laravel blade

Comment: You should edit your question to include this information, not post it as an answer. And you should accept an answer. Glad it worked out :)

Comment: Oh, sorry I didn't see what :)